# Scala scraper select a tag with attribute presents

Tags: scala, jsoup

How to select a tag with some attribute present, e.g. `a` tag with `href` attribute `<a href="...">` using Scala **scraper** using a single query instead of multiple unsafe queries like following?

```
val browser = JsoupBrowser()
val doc = browser.get("https://...")
val a = doc >> element("a")
val h = a >> attr("href")
```

Comment: what's wrong with [`doc.select`](https://jsoup.org/)? If there is one thing that CSS selectors should be able to do, it's selecting dom elements, or am I missing something?

Comment: `doc >>` is probably the same as `doc.select`. However, I am having a trouble finding the correct query

Comment: "correct query" to do *what*? You can write arbitrary queries to find every needle in the specified `#haystack`, and every `[color=black]` cat in any `.dark` room (if you want, you can also find its `+` siblings, and `> ` children). But how is anyone supposed to help you if you are neither giving the input data, nor the desired output, nor your attempt, nor an explanation what exactly went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I was looking for a query for `<a href="...">`. I forgot to escape it. So, it wasn't displayed

Comment: Anyway, thank you. You pointed out my mistake by selecting `'a'` instead of `'[href]'`

Comment: `doc.select("a[href]")`

Comment: @ntviet18 Oh well, so the most important part of your question was actually hidden as an invalid tag in the MD source code of your question. Sorry, didn't think to look there :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp), you can use a tag selector `a` combined with an attribute selector `[href]`:

```
doc.select("a[href]")
```

In general, you can also further constrain the values of the attribute with the `[name=value]` syntax. If you only want to check the existence of the attribute, `[name]` should be enough.